# Android databinding error: cannot find symbol of my custom @BindingAdapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I'm trying to add an app global custom `@BindingAdapter`. I created `TextViewBinding.kt` file, and put it to the separate package `com.my.app.binding.TextViewBinding`. When I compile the app, I get the error

> error: cannot find symbol
>               TextViewAdapterKt.setTypeface(this.titleTextView, viewedJavaLangStringNormalJavaLangStringBold);

If I put the adapter function into an Activity, there are no errors. But, because it's app global adapter, I don't want it to belong to any particular view. So, where I should place the adapter function to get rid of the error?

**TextViewAdapter.kt**

```
@BindingAdapter("typeface")
fun TextView.setTypeface(style: String) {
    when (style) {
        "bold" -> setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD)
        else -> setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL)
    }
}
```

**my_list_item.xml**

```xml
...
    <TextView app:typeface='@{viewed ? "normal" : bold"}' ... />
...
```

Comment: Try with `@JvmStatic` above `@BindingAdapter` annotation & check again.

Comment: I cannot add `@JvmStatic` to a function, but I already tried to create object with `@JvmStatic` method, and class with companion object, but the error still there.

Comment: May be because it's **extension function**, it doesn't work for `@BindingAdapter`.

Comment: No, I tried basic function, but nothing changes. Inside an Activity file it works.

Comment: I just forgot to add package declaration to the adapter file :) but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the error reason. I just forgot to add package declaration to the top of `TextViewAdapter.kt` file.